# Overlapping contenido y footer

Tags: html, css

me encuentro desarrollando un sitio y tengo un problema con la plantilla [AdminLTE](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html). No soy un experto en CSS ni mucho menos, pero el problema surge que mi contenido, solo un div que gracias a [ACE Editor](https://ace.c9.io/) se convierte en un editor de texto, sobrepasa los márgenes dados y se superpone al footer.

Dejo algunas imágenes para mostrar el inconveniente; he intentado solucionarlo aplicando algunas reglas pero sin resultado positivo.

#html, body

```
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

#editor

```
position: absolute;
    height: 73%;
    width: 81%;
    font-family: Monaco,Menlo,"Ubuntu Mono",Consolas,source-code-pro,monospace !important;
    font-size:16px;
```

[image: Sin saltos de línea, ventana maximizada]
[image: Con saltos de línea, ventana maximizada]
[image: Rezised]
[image: Rezised, div y footer desastrozo]
[image: Rezised, div y footer desastrozo x2]

Supongo que internamente la plantilla de AdminLTE hará uso de mediaqueries para poder ajustar el ancho-alto de cada pantalla. El problema surge cuando se re-ajusta la pantalla, el div central solapa al footer.

Desde ya, muchas gracias por todo y cualquier comentario (constructivo/educativo) es bienvenido :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de mucho buscar, ya se había respondido algo similar.
Lo dejo para quien le sirva :)

[Solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914804/how-to-make-ace-editor-manually-resizable-just-like-htmls-textarea)